# embedding a website inside a modal box on a different domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, modal-dialog, fancybox

I need to embed an iframe on different domain, that when click opens a modal box using fancy box.

It would work something like this.

user clicks image
Once click loads a modal box(fancybox) that holds the iframe

I need to do this because the fancybox needs to take up the majority of the screen 960x700

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it. Check out their [API](http://fancybox.net/api) for more details on how to use it

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.pack.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" media="screen" />
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                /* This is basic - uses default settings */


                $("a.iframe").fancybox({
                    'transitionIn'  :   'elastic', //Used for animation, delete if not needed
                    'transitionOut' :   'elastic', //Used for animation, delete if not needed
                    'speedIn'       :   600,  //Used for animation, delete if not needed
                    'speedOut'      :   200, //Used for animation, delete if not needed
                    'overlayShow'   :   false, //Used for animation, delete if not needed
                    'width'         :   650, //Set your width
                    'height'        :   500 //Set your height
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="iframe" href="http://www.google.com">Click to open fancy box</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks brandon that worked! I' need to combine all of the js so I'm only linking a single file then its ready to go!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I was able to help.